# Show The Jordan Normal Form Of $\varphi$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, partial-differential-equations, jordan-normal-form

> Fix a nonnegative integer $n$, and consider the linear space 
>   $$\mathbb{R}_n\left [x,y \right ] := \left\{ 
> \sum_{\substack{
>  i_1,i_2;\\
> i_1+i_2\leq n}}a_{i_1i_2}x^{i_1}y^{i_2}\quad\Big|{}_{\quad}a_{i_1i_2}\in \mathbb{R} ; \ i_1,i_2 \text{ are non-negative integers}\right \}$$
>   over $\mathbb{R}$ where two
>   operations, *addition* and *scalar multiplication*, are defined as usual. 
>   $\\$
>
> A linear map $\varphi$ from $\mathbb{R}_n\left [x,y \right ]$ to $\mathbb{R}_n\left[x,y \right ]$ defined as following:
>
> $$\forall f(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}_n\left [x,y \right ],\quad\varphi(f):=2\frac{\partial f }{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial f }{\partial y}.\quad$$
>   $\\$
>   Show  the  jordan normal form of $\varphi$.

---

When $n=1,$ $$span\{2,x,-\frac{1}{2}x+y\}=\mathbb{R}_1\left [x,y \right ], $$$$\varphi(2,x,-\frac{1}{2}x+y)=(2,x,-\frac{1}{2}x+y)\left(\begin{array}{cc|cc} 
0 &  1& 0\\ 
 0&  0& 0\\ 
 \hline 0&  0& 0
\end{array}\right).$$

When  $n=2,$  $$span\{1,x,y,xy,x^2,y^2\}=\mathbb{R}_2\left [x,y \right ], $$it is not difficult to calculate the  jordan normal form of $\varphi$ is

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|cc|c} 0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0\\ 0&  0&  1&  0&  0& 0\\ 0&  0&  0&  0&  0& 0\\ \hline0&  0& 0 &  0&  1& 0\\  0&  0& 0 &  0&  0& 0\\  \hline 0&  0& 0 &  0&  0& 0\\ 
\end{array}\right).$$

But how to generalize it to  any  integer $n$ and  prove the generalization is  correct ？

Answer (score 1):

There is an anther approach.

Let $f^{k}_{1}=(x-2y)^k (k=0，1，\cdots，n)$$, \varphi(f^{k}_1)=0.$For a fixed $ k(\geq 1),$We only need to find $f^{k}_{t}(t=1，2\cdots，k),$such that $\varphi (f^{k}_{t+1})=f^{k}_{t},$ $$\varphi(f^{k}_{1},f^{k}_{2},\cdots,f^{k}_{k+1})$$$$=(f^{k}_{1},f^{k}_{2},\cdots,f^{k}_{k+1})\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 &  &  & \\ 
 & 0 &  1&  & \\ 
 &  &  \ddots&  \ddots& \\ 
 &  &  & 0 & 1\\ 
 &  &  & & 0
\end{pmatrix}_{(k+1)\times(k+1)}.$$ 
Using  some knowledge of *First order linear partial differential equation*, it is not difficult to find those $f^{k}_{t}$s.

Answer (score 0):

I would have posted the followig train of thoughts as a comment to my question,but the symbols failed to display on mobile devices. $\\$

By using the mathematical inductive  method,we only need to prove：

For any fixed integer $n$, $\textbf{(1)}$ the order of jordan normal form of $\varphi$  is  $\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2} $;
$\textbf{(2)} $ the minimal  polynomial of  $\varphi$ is $\lambda^{n+1};$
$\textbf{(3)}$ $\dim\ker(\varphi)$ is $n+1$$\left(i. e.rank(\varphi)=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right).$

---

It is not difficult to get $\textbf{(1)}$ and $\textbf{(2)}$.With regard to $\textbf{(3)}$，we just observe that
 $$span \left \{ \varphi(1)\arrowvert\varphi(x),\varphi(y)\right \}=span\left\{1\right\};$$$$span \left \{ \varphi(1)\arrowvert\varphi(x),\varphi(y)\arrowvert\varphi(xy),\varphi(x^2),\varphi(y^2)\right \}=span\left\{1\right\}\oplus span\left \{ x,y \right \}; $$$$span \left \{ \varphi(1)\arrowvert\varphi(x),\varphi(y)\arrowvert\varphi(xy),\varphi(x^2),\varphi(y^2)\arrowvert\varphi(x^2y),\varphi(xy^2),\varphi(x^3),\varphi(y^3)\right \}=span\left\{1\right\}\oplus span\left \{ x,y \right \}\oplus span\left\{xy,x^2,y^2\right\};$$$$\cdots\quad\cdots\quad\cdots\quad\cdots\quad.$$

---

$\\$And then，$\textbf{(1)}+\textbf{(2)}+\textbf{(3)} \Longrightarrow \textbf{(4)}$
For any fixed integer $n$, the jordan normal form of $\varphi$ is a nilpotent matrix its order is  $\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$ and the total number of jordan blocks is  $n+1$.
Those are

$(0)_{1\times1},\begin{pmatrix}
 0&  1 \\ 
 0&  0\\ 
\end{pmatrix}_{2\times 2},\begin{pmatrix}
 0&  1&  0\\ 
 0&  0&  1\\ 
 0&  0&  0\\  
\end{pmatrix}_{3\times3},\cdots \cdots,\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 &  &  & \\ 
 & 0 &  1&  & \\ 
 &  &  \ddots&  \ddots& \\ 
 &  &  & 0 & 1\\ 
 &  &  & & 0
\end{pmatrix}_{(n+1)\times(n+1)}.$

Comment: Hint: An appropriate change of basis (i.e., replacing $x$ and $y$ by $ax+by$ and $cx+dy$ for some appropriately chosen $a,b,c,d$) will transform your $\varphi$ into $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}$. But the structure of $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is fairly simple to see (the $x^i y^j$ form a Jordan basis).